# Multiple $expand and $select within same table

Tags: powerbi, odata

I am trying to $select specific columns from table (if_sites) from OData Feed, however 2 of these columns are Tables and I am only able to find a way to expand one, but not 2 or more of the tables within Table *if_sites*

Table Name: if_sites

| if_name | if_siteid |
| --- | --- |
| Site A | 10eed1 |
| Site B | 17fcc2 |

if_sites also contains the following tables,

| if_if_locality_if_sites | if_if_site_if_schedule |
| --- | --- |
| if_name | if_name |
| if_if_locality_if_sites | if_scheduleid |
| if_if_LocalityType |  |

[Visual Representation of *if_sites* Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnjWI.png)

This is what I have so far.

```
= OData.Feed(https://XXXXXX/v9.2/if_sites?$select=if_siteid,if_name,if_if_locality_if_site&$expand=if_if_locality_if_site($select=if_name,if_if_locality_if_site,if_LocalityType), null, [Implementation="2.0"])
```

In addition to the expanded column above, I would ALSO like to add *$expand= if_if_site_if_schedule($select=if_name)* within the same query

I suppose I could generate a second query,adding the following and just establish the relationship.

```
= OData.Feed(https://XXXXXX/v9.2/if_sites?$select=if_siteid,if_if_site_if_schedule&$expand=if_if_site_if_schedule($select=if_name), null, [Implementation="2.0"])
```

but surely there must be a way to do it in one query.

I tried

```
$expand=if_if_locality_if_site($expand=if_if_site_schedule;$select=if_name)
```

,

```
$expand=if_if_locality_if_site,if_if_site_if_schedule
```

```
= .../v9.2/if_sites?$select=if_siteid,if_name,if_if_locality_if_site&$expand=if_if_locality_if_site/if_name,if_if_site_if_schedule/if_name", null, [Implementation="2.0"])
```

and various combinations but I get NOT found,(Found a path traversing multiple navigation properties. Please rephrase the query such that each expand path contains only type segments and navigation properties.), incorrect synthax at position 'x', comments relating to nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to have done the trick,

```
= OData.Feed("https://XXXXX/v9.2/if_sites?$select=if_if_locality_if_site&$expand=if_if_locality_if_site($select=if_name,if_if_locality_if_site,if_LocalityType), if_if_site_if_schedule($select=if_scheduleid,if_name)", null, [Implementation="2.0"])
```

I tried to `$select` only columns which I wanted to see the data for, but I ran into trouble.

Omitting specific columns from `$select` generated issues with the relationships (i.e., rows would display incorrect data), such as all 400k+ rows showing the same if_scheduleid.

The Loading of the table takes ages, probably a lot faster than my previous way of doing it via Power Query though where I selected the table, expanded relevant fields (nested tables) and then removed Other Columns (100+ extra columns).